# What does 传承跨越沧桑的壁垒 mean?

Tags: translation

传承 impart and inherit
跨越 stride across; leap over
沧桑 vicissitude
的 poss.
壁垒 rampart; barrier
I came with 'passing the obstacles' but I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an English translation from YouTube

> [image]

and in text form:

> Inheritance over the barriers of vicissitudes of life

Without directly translating every word specifically we could change this to something more user-friendly like:

- An inheritance that transcends the barrier of time

You might even be able to fit "changes" in their as well to make it a little truer to the original Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It is very straight forward using Google Translate

传承 - impart and inherit

跨越 - leap across

沧桑的 - of vicissitudes

壁垒 - barrier

I would like to talk about the term 沧桑

沧桑 came from the idiom 沧海桑田

- 沧海 (vast sea)
- 桑田 (mulberry field)

Together, it means 'vast sea became a mulberry field'. It describes unimaginable changes that occurred over eons

沧桑:

- on a geologic time scale refers to billions of year (vicissitudes through eons)
- on a personal lifetime scale refers to a few years or a few tens of years - not longer than a typical human's life span (vicissitudes through life)
- on a cultural heritage time scale refers to hundreds or thousands of years (vicissitudes through time)

> "传承跨越沧桑的壁垒" =  "leap across the barrier of vicissitudes through time to impart and inherit"

Comment: Quote:- "沧海桑田" ---  "on a geologic time scale refers to billions of year (vicissitudes through eons)" Yes, since I came across this Idiom a long time ago, I've always been awed by its implication with regards to the "antediluvian" ancientness of the Chinese civilization. 沧海桑田 implies that sea-beds could transform into mulberry fields and vice versa given enough time, measured in aeons, with rise and fall of global sea levels. For the ancient Chinese to have noticed this, they must have observed Nature for 1000s of years. The Chinese civilization is therefore older that we imagined or told.

Comment: I can imagine ancient people would notice all the seashells found in high mountains implicated it might have been a seabed eons ago

Comment: If so, the Idiom would be 沧海高峰? :)

Comment: 沧海 contrasts 桑田 to indicate the huge changes in situations that render returning to the original state impossible, I believe "曾經沧海, 難為桑田" was the origin of 沧海桑田. I don't recall who wrote that then.

Comment: You are confusing 沧海桑田  with 曾经沧海难为水